# Rotation through images using JAVA FX

Tags: animation, javafx

Essentially I'm trying to make a glowing warning image.
Starts just being a red triangle, but then emits a glow, then goes back to a red triangle.

But I'm trying to figure out a way to implement it.

I thought of using timelines, but it will only show the last picture, and stay on it.

I've replaced my Imaged with ones publicly available.
With these images it should come up "Number 1" for 2 seconds, "Number 2" for 2 seconds, "number 3" for 2 seconds, then go back to number 1 and repeat indefinitely.

Other than my way, if someone has a better way to make my objective happen in a different way with Java FX (That isn't too complex, I'm pretty new to Java FX). I'm all ears

Thanks again!
Here is the code I've fiddled with.

```
public class GlowEffect extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Image img1 = new Image("http://clipart-library.com/images/dc9rEEbdi.jpg");
        Image img2 = new Image("http://clipart-library.com/data_images/356167.png");
        Image img3 = new Image("http://clipart-library.com/data_images/123556.png");
        ImageView imgview1 = new ImageView();
        imgview1.setX(0);
        imgview1.setY(0);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        
        
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> imgview1.setImage(img1)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> imgview1.setImage(img2)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> imgview1.setImage(img3))

        );

        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        Pane pane = new Pane(imgview1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: All your `KeyFrame`s have the same time point. So you’re executing all three `setImage(...)` calls at the “same time”. You need to give them different times, e.g. 0, 2, and 4 seconds.

Comment: If you are just looking to have a single image emit a glow, you can also use the [Glow](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/Glow.html) class for that (instead of having to rotate through images).